# Wordpress store front theme

Tags: wordpress, gridview, themes, store

I am working for a client so I am not able to provide the most of the details here. So if someone already used this theme http://themeforest.net/item/wpa-storefront-the-ultimate-wpecommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/61891 please let me know how to get the last grid view option to show up via the admin. This is another example that I came across - http://www.sports-mb.com/. I am able to see the option under "theme options" and I typed in a category id but nothing shows up. I am not sure if there is a on/off control to have it show on the page. Please advise me.  I am able to show the first two showcases but not the last one.

Comment: I see the div opened and closed in the view source like other examples I provided but no content. I also noticed the file used in the home.php {include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/homepage/show_posts_gridview.php');} but not sure why no content

Comment: For future reference, you can try wordpress.stackexchange.com for (hopefully) better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by changing some settings. I was able to show post instead of product categories, so I went with that option. I might have questions later if client needs something else and if I am struck.thanks for reading.